# Making the second column of the table of contents clear the page header

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

I use the following to split the table of contents into two colums, so that it will fit on one page:

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \tableofcontents
\end{multicols*}
```

However, the result is the following. The second column starts at the top of the page, to the right of the "Contents" heading. I would prefer it if the second column would start at exactly the same height as the first column instead.

If while doing this the opportunity arises, it would be even better if the chapter groups were not split across the columns. In the image, that would result in chapter 6 being moved to the second column entirely rather than having the beginning on the first column and the continuation on the second.

[image: Table of contents page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal working example (MWE) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve can be done in at least two ways.

The appearances will vary slightly depending on the inter-element spaces. But basically they remain the same.

---

**Method 1: Without Using `multicols`**

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \twocolumn[%
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \chapter*{\contentsname
      \@mkboth{%
        \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}]%
  \@starttoc{toc}
  \onecolumn}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-50]

\section{Research domain}

\section{Another section}

\subsection{And a subsection}

\chapter{Literature Study}

\section{Section Alpha}
\section{Section Beta}
\section{Section Gamma}
\section{Section Delta}
\section{Section Epsilon}
\section{Section Zeta}

\chapter{More Chapter Alpha}
\section{Section Alpha}
\section{Section Beta}
\section{Section Gamma}
\section{Section Delta}
\section{Section Epsilon}
\section{Section Zeta}

\chapter{More Chapter Beta}
\section{Section Alpha}
\section{Section Beta}
\section{Section Gamma}
\section{Section Delta}
\section{Section Epsilon}
\section{Section Zeta}


\chapter{More Chapter Gamma}
\section{Section Alpha}
\section{Section Beta}
\section{Section Gamma}
\section{Section Delta}
\section{Section Epsilon}
\section{Section Zeta}

\chapter{More Chapter Delta}
\section{Section Alpha}
\section{Section Beta}
\section{Section Gamma}
\section{Section Delta}
\section{Section Epsilon}
\section{Section Zeta}


\chapter{More Chapter Epsilon}
\section{Section Alpha}
\section{Section Beta}
\section{Section Gamma}
\section{Section Delta}
\section{Section Epsilon}
\section{Section Zeta}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\chapter{References}

\appendix

\chapter{Code Listings}

\end{document}
```

---

**Method 2: Using `multicols`**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\chapter*{\contentsname
  \@mkboth{%
    \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \@starttoc{toc}
\end{multicols*}
\makeatother


\chapter{Introduction}
 
.........................


\appendix

\chapter{Code Listings}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**How are These Done?**

The basic principle over here is to put the `\contentsname`
in one column and actual contents in two column. Then switch back
to single column for main text. To actually achieve the effects,
we hack into the internals of the `\tableofcontents`
command.

The `\twocolumn` command before the text will  split it into two
columns.  The problem is, `\twocolumn` starts a new page.  Fortunately,
it has an optional argument which lets you specify one column content
before two column content. See [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs) for details.

In the second method, we put the `\contentsname`
as usual and then put the actual contents in two column
using `{multicols*}{2}`.